# Add 1 Day to a Date

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating an alarm clock app for IOS. Long story short, I have configured the DatePicker to display only hours and minutes.

My problem is that When the user inputs 6:00 AM, I want it to be for the following morning, where Xcode now is assuming it is the same day.

EX: The user goes to sleep at 10 pm on a Wednesday and sets his alarm for 6:00 AM Thursday. My app is assuming the 6:00 AM is meant for Wednesday. How can I fix this?

Comment: What research have you done so far? What code have you written? This question has all the information you need to solve your issue (for example: create a date component to add 1 to the day): https://stackoverflow.com/q/24089999/558933

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reliable way to get the next occurrence of a time is `nextDate(after:matching:matchingPolicy:` of `Calendar` because it considers also daylight saving changes.

assuming `datePicker` is the `NSDatePicker` instance:

```
let date = datePicker.date

let calendar = Calendar.current
// get hour and minute components of the given date
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
// calculate the next occurrence of the date components from now
let nextOccurrence = calendar.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using the [AFDateHelper](https://github.com/melvitax/DateHelper) library personally.

```
import AFDateHelper

let tomorrowDate = dateFromPicker.adjust(.day, offset: 1)
```