# Google Calendar API iOS Quickstart

Tags: ios, google-calendar-api, xcode9

Got the QuickstartApp working, but it pulls all future events from the current date. I'd like to get the events prior to the current date.
This part of the code sets the current date:

query.timeMin = GTLRDateTime(date: Date())

I can't figure out the syntax to get a different date. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, try something like this:

```
// Specify date components
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.year = 2019
dateComponents.month = 7
dateComponents.day = 11
dateComponents.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EDT") // Eastern Daylight Time
dateComponents.hour = 8
dateComponents.minute = 34

// Create date from components
let userCalendar = Calendar.current // user calendar
let futureDate = userCalendar.date(from: dateComponents)

query.timeMin = GTLRDateTime(date: futureDate)
```

There are other methods you can use to create a different `date` [found in this *very* related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089999/how-do-you-create-a-swift-date-object).

Comment: Awesome!  With a little tweaking, I got it to work.  Thanks.