# Filter by date component in Realm

Tags: swift, date, filter, realm, predicate

Hi i want to filter results by year number in realm, I did something but its return type is LazyFilterCollection<>. How can i fix it to get Results? I think it could be done using NSPredicate, but I can't understand how to use date component in predicates.

Here is my Training model.

```
    class Training: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id = 0
    @objc dynamic var date = NSDate()
    var exercises = RealmSwift.List<TrainingExercise>()

    convenience init(date: NSDate, exercise: TrainingExercise) {
        self.init()
        self.exercises.append(exercise)
    }

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

And here is expression where i'm trying to filter it.

```
let trainingsFilteredByYear = trainings.filter {
        return Calendar.current.component(.year, from: $0.date as Date) == 2018
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not that simple. Results.filter takes nspredicate or a predicate format string.

```
let trainingsBetweenDates = realm.objects(Trainings.self).filter("date BETWEEN {%@, %@}", startDate, endDate)
```

you can make the boundary dates yourself using the methods described here:[How do you create a swift Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089999/how-do-you-create-a-swift-date-object)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it