# Convert date to format Day, date month year

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert a date string from `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` to "day, date month year", something like this "Monday, 01 January 2018".

I'm using my helper function which converts a date string from one format to another. In the function below I'm not sure what parameter needs to be passed for `to`:

```
func convertDate(from inputFormat: String, to outputFormat: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = inputFormat
    if let dateInLocal = dateFormatter.date(from: self) {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = outputFormat
        dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
        dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: dateInLocal)
    }
    return "NA"
}
```

Using above extension like below

```
dateAndName = date.convertDate(from:"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", to: "")
```

Comment: don't escape the Z. The Z means UTC time. If you ignore it you will get a date with current timezone.

Comment: These may help you 
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/52297497/5170595](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52297497/5170595)
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/33344575/5170595](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33344575/5170595)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the documentation for date formats.

`EEEE` gives the full weekday name.
`MMMM` gives the full month name.
`dd` gives a two-digit month number.
`yyyy` gives a four-digit year number.

Do not quote the `Z` in the input format. The `Z` in the date string represents the timezone of the date string. If you quote the `Z` in the date format then the `Z` is essentially ignored in the string as a timezone indicator and the date formatter will parse the date string as if it were local time and give you the wrong result.

Here's your cleaned up code:

```
func convertDate(from inputFormat: String, to outputFormat: String) -> String? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = inputFormat
    dateFormatter.local = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

    if let dateInLocal = dateFormatter.date(from: self) {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = outputFormat
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
        return dateFormatter.string(from: dateInLocal)
    }

    return nil
}

dateAndName = date.convertDate(from:"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", to: "EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy")
```

Note that this function should return an optional string. Let the caller decided how to deal with invalid input.

Also note the special locale used to parse the input string.