# Accessibility Voice One for Date in a String

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, voiceover

I have below code.

```
let text = "as of 07/29/2020"
textLabel.text = text
```

Voice Over read it - "as of 07 slash 29 slash 2 Thousand 20"

How can i make it to pronounce like "as of July, 29 2 Thousand 20"

Comment: Take a look at this very helpful link ⟹https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#date-time-and-numbers 

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**
Not sure exactly what you are trying to solve. But hopefully this helps.

Step 1: You need to use the accessibility label property `label.accessibilityLabel = "some string"`

Step 2: Convert your date into a more friendly string for voice over. You can do this by using a `Date()` object and format it differently for the label and the voice-over label. Here is a link for creating dates in swift.

Below is the link to the documentation and the section that mentions accessibility labels.

***Playground Example: Your code will then look something like this.***

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let label = UILabel()

let dateForLabel = formatDate(date: Date(), style: .short)
let dateStringForLabel = "as of \(dateForLabel)"
label.text = dateStringForLabel

let dateForVoiceOverLabel = formatDate(date: Date(), style: .long)
let dateStringForVoiceOver = "as of \(dateForVoiceOverLabel)"
label.accessibilityLabel = dateStringForVoiceOver

func formatDate(date: Date, style: DateFormatter.Style) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = style
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none

    let date = date

    // US English Locale (en_US)
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    return  dateFormatter.string(from: date) // Jan 2, 2001
}
```

**Link to create a Date() object**
[How do you create a Swift Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089999/how-do-you-create-a-swift-date-object)

**Link to apple documentation on Accessibility labels**
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility_for_ios_and_tvos/supporting_voiceover_in_your_app

"Update Your App’s Accessibility
For elements that were not accessible to VoiceOver, start by improving their accessibility labels and hints:

The `accessibilityLabel` property provides descriptive text that VoiceOver reads when the user selects an element.

The `accessibilityHint` property provides additional context (or actions) for the selected element.

Accessibility labels are very important, because they provide the text that VoiceOver reads. A good accessibility label should be short and informative. It is important to note that a `UILabel` and an `accessibilityLabel` are different things. By default, VoiceOver reads the text associated with standard UIKit controls such as `UILabel` and `UIButton`. However these controls can also have corresponding `accessibilityLabel` properties to add more detail about the label or button..

Depending on the context, hints aren’t always necessary. In some cases, the label provides enough context. If you feel like you’re saying too much in an accessibility label, consider moving that text into a hint.

To ensure that users understand the intent of your interface, you might need to set some accessibility labels manually. Accessibility labels and hints can either be set in Xcode’s Identity Inspector or programmatically."

Comment: Another captivating link for this VoiceOver problem ⟹ https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#date-time-and-numbers 